# PHP changes the file_get_contents param url

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm using the following line with to get the page content:

```
$handle = file_get_contents(
    "http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?show=users&action=msg&section=send", 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    1000, 
    19000);
```

And then, I'm getting the following message:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?show=users&action=msg **§ion=send**):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

(Please take a note at the bolded part).

What happened to it? Why does it changes the url param?

Comment: `&sect;` is the html entity for § ... but there is no `;`, this is strange.

Comment: have you tried `urlencode()`-ing your URL?

Comment: If you're looking at this in a browser, see View Source if PHP is actually outputting that or if it's just your browser rendering an entity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PHP is changing querystring parameters.

If you are reading that message in the browser, it should be just a matter of how the output is HTML formatted. So, the 403 error you are getting it should not be related to some unwanted url transformation.

Comment: But well, the URL is loading in my browser without any 403 header error, it's loading everywhere, until I use `file_get_contents` to grab the content from it.